# Table is mutating when trigger is trying to query a view

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am getting ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CUSTOM.CLOSE_WORK_FLOW_ACTIVITY' when am trying write a trigger as follows

```
 create or replace trigger CLOSE_ACTIVITY 
    BEFORE UPDATE OF STATUS ON ORDERS referencing new as new
    for each row
    declare 
    ln_order_count NUMBER:=0;
    ln_act_id_no_sn NUMBER:=0;
    ln_req_id NUMBER:=0;
    ln_wq_id Number;
 BEGIN
     if :new.status='COMPLETE' then
       select request_id into ln_req_id from all_orders where id=:new.id;
   --Useful code
     endif;
end;
```

Here ORDERS is a table, and all_orders is a view which is querying on ORDERS table. Now when the trigger gets fired I get the above-mentioned error.

Can you anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Mutating table error occurs when a trigger is trying to update a table that it read from. In your case it is the ORDERS table.

It is best to avoid triggers for these kinds of activities, or use a statement-level trigger. If both of these are not viable, try changing your trigger to `AFTER UPDATE of STATUS on ORDERS`

This should solve it as the update is completed and then the select is issued. (But make sure changing it to an AFTER trigger does not affect your business logic)

Comment: I have tried using AFTER, even that didn't help. Also am not trying to update the table here. Am trying to query from the view which is querying the table internally.